# How to calculate numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

here is my code.

```
A = [86.14803712, 85.25496701, 86.50334271, 86.0266668,  86.61455594, 86.90445213, 86.65519315, 87.10116762, 87.08173861]
B = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    c = A[i]-A[i-1]
    B.append(c)
    print(c)
```

I want to get the differences between two continuous numbers in this list, eg,(85.25496701-86.14803712). So in the results, I should have eight numbers as results.

But the results I get are:

```
-0.9337014900000042
-0.8930701099999965 
1.2483756999999969
-0.4766759099999973
0.5878891400000015
0.2898961899999932
-0.24925897999999336
0.4459744699999959
-0.019429009999996083
```

I don't need -0.9337014900000042  since it comes from the first number subtract the last number in the list. What should I do the fix it? Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Comment: Simplest: `B = [n - m for (m, n) in zip(A, A[1:])]`  This works because `zip` stops when it exhausts the shortest iterable.

Comment: Hint: -1 is a valid index to a list.

Comment: This works too... `print(reduce(lambda r, e: r + [A[A.index(e) + 1] - e] if A.index(e) + 1 < len(A) else r, A, []))`

Answer (score 1):

That's the strength and the weakness of python: index `-1` is always valid when the list isn't empty, which can lead to programs not crashing but not doing what you want.

For those operations, it's better to use `zip` to interleave the list with a sliced version of itself without the first number:

```
A = [86.14803712, 85.25496701, 86.50334271, 86.0266668,  86.61455594, 86.90445213, 86.65519315, 87.10116762, 87.08173861]

diffs = [ac-ap for ac,ap in zip(A[1:],A)]
```

or with `itertools.islice` to avoid creating a new list to iterate on it:

```
import itertools
diffs = [ac-ap for ac,ap in zip(itertools.islice(A,1,None),A)]
```

result (8 values):

```
[-0.8930701099999965, 1.2483756999999969, -0.4766759099999973, 0.5878891400000015, 0.2898961899999932, -0.24925897999999336, 0.4459744699999959, -0.019429009999996083]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in base Python, but you might like the semantic clarity of Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(A).diff().values[1:]

array([-0.89307011,  1.2483757 , -0.47667591,  0.58788914,  0.28989619,
       -0.24925898,  0.44597447, -0.01942901])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
B = [x-y for x, y in zip(A[1:], A)]
print(B)  # -> [-0.8930701099999965, 1.2483756999999969, -0.4766759099999973, 0.5878891400000015, 0.2898961899999932, -0.24925897999999336, 0.4459744699999959, -0.019429009999996083]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you star from a correct index. In your current code, in the first iteration of the loop you will be computing `A[0] - A[-1]`. Hence, you need to start `i` from `1` to ensure in the first iteration you compute the value of `A[1] - A[0]`. The corrected version of your code is here:

```
A = [86.14803712, 85.25496701, 86.50334271, 86.0266668,  86.61455594, 86.90445213, 86.65519315, 87.10116762, 87.08173861]
B = []
i = 0
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    c = A[i]-A[i-1]
    B.append(c)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the loop subtracts the first element to the last because the loop starts at index 0 and subtracts it from index -1 (python takes -1 as the last index of a list). A better solution imo would be:

```
A = [86.14803712, 85.25496701, 86.50334271, 86.0266668,  86.61455594, 
86.90445213, 86.65519315, 87.10116762, 87.08173861]
B = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    c = -(A[i]-A[i+1])
    B.append(c)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

```
result = [x-y for x,y in zip(A[1:], A[:-1])]
```