# Partitioning a list into sublists with offset 1

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following list:

```
x=["A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A", "D"]
```

I wonder how does one partition into sublists of length 2 with offset 1 such that one gets:

```
#[["A", "B"], ["B", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "B"], ["B", "A"], ["A", 
# "D"], ["D", "D"], ["D", "A"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "A"], ["A", "D"]]
```

Also is there a generalised method for this? For example for different size of partition and different offsets? Suppose I want to partition into sublists of 3 with offset 2: for which I'd get

```
#[["A", "B", "B"], ["B", "C", "B"], ["B", "A", "D"], ["D", "D", 
# "A"], ["A", "B", "A"]]
```

Is it possible to write this as a function, so for a given list, with given partition size and given number of offset it finds the sublists?

Comment: `list(zip(x, x[1:]))` ?

Comment: @jpp yes, and that is probably a duplicate

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Agreed, I don't know where to find the dup :(.

Comment: @jpp I do :):).

Comment: (I'm also guilty of answering a classical dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710572/6451573) ...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have edited the question, please remove duplication as it is way more generalised than the linked post you've put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list `x` with `n` items, you need to create a new list with `n-1` items, each item is a pair of items that follow each other. It's easy to do with running over the items of the list from the first item until the second to last, and create a list for every one of those items with that item (`x[i]`) and the one that comes after him (`x[i+1]`)

```
result = [[x[i], x[i+1]] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

And for the more generic case:

```
offset = 2
sublist_size = 3
result = [[x[i + n] for n in range(sublist_size)] for i in range(0, len(x) - sublist_size, offset)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this is there a generalised method for this? For example for different size of partition and different offsets? Suppose I want to partition into sublists of 3 with offset 2: for which I'd get [["A", "B", "B"], ["B", "C", "B"], ["B", "A", "D"], ["D", "D", 
  "A"], ["A", "B", "A"]]

Comment: I have edited the question, if you add this to the answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: although that works, I think you're getting some downvotes because `range(len(x)-1)` is horribly unpythonic compared to `zip`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a slice of the list after the first element and do this with `zip`

```
    >>> x=["A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A", "D"]
    >>> [list(a) for a in zip(x,x[1:])]
    [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'D'], ['D',
    'D'], ['D', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'D']]
```

Comment: you can avoid "hard" slicing of `x` by using `zip(x,itertools.islice(x,1,None))`